# How to download in overpass turbo a specific path

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

in overpass turbo how can I download Way number 209583332, I got it from OpenStreetMap site which is a

```
highway=path
```

If use `highway=path` in the wizard it selects all paths from the map window and I only want number 209583332.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download it directly from the [OSM API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API): https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/way/209583332. However don't use this API for bulk downloads, see the [API usage policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/api/) for more information.

For downloading a specific element via Overpass API just query for this ID:

```
way(209583332);
out;
```

Example: http://overpass.osm.rambler.ru/cgi/interpreter?data=way(209583332);out;

Comment: Can you download it in gpx or any other georeferenced format?

Comment: I managed to download it as a gpx file by having Overpass fix the query:


`way(209583332);


/*added by auto repair*/
(._;>;);
/*end of auto repair*/
out;`

Comment: This change doesn't change the output format. Overpass API supports various [output formats](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Output_Format_.28out.29) (xml, json, csv) but no GPX. OSM API supports only XML for most outputs, except for notes and uploaded GPS traces. overpass turbo supports GPX exports, I guess it uses some library for this task.